# How to fit a lognormal distribution in Python?

Tags: python, scipy

I want to fit lognormal distribution to my data, using python `scipy.stats.lognormal.fit`. According to the [manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html), `fit` returns *shape, loc, scale* parameters. But, lognormal distribution normally needs only [two parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lognormal): mean and standard deviation.

How to interpret the results from scipy `fit` function? How to get mean and standard deviation?

Answer (score 4):

From [scipy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html):  "If log x is normally distributed with mean mu and variance sigma**2, then x is log-normally distributed with shape parameter sigma and scale parameter exp(mu)."

The location parameter shifts the lognormal distribution along the x-axis so the lower bound wouldn't be zero (which is what the location parameter defaults to.)